# Composite Primary key in JPA EclipseLink DynamicPersistence

Tags: jpa, persistence, eclipselink, composite-primary-key

Eclipselink Dynamic Persistence allow multiple primary key by **:** `DynamicTypeBuilder.setPrimaryKeyFields(String primarykeysField...)`

But how can i find entity object(instance) by **`EntityManager.find( Entity Class , Object primaryKey)` method to find entity in case of composite primary key**(Multiple Primarykey) (because of no IdClass or EmbeddedId) **in Dynamic Persistence** .

EclipseLink take List of pk in the find() operation but if composite pk key defined in example -

---

```
Entity = Person
Fields = username,emailId,firstName,lastName
Composite PK = username,emailId
```

---

```
Class<?> clazz = new DynamicClassLoader(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()).createDynamicClass("Person");
DynamicTypeBuilder builder = new DynamicTypeBuilder(clazz, null, "Person");
DynamicType dynamicType = builder.getType();
builder.setPrimaryKeyFields(["username","emailId"]);
builder.addDirectMapping("username",String.class,"username");
builder.addDirectMapping("emailId",String.class,"emailId");
builder.addDirectMapping("firstName",String.class,"firstName");
builder.addDirectMapping("lastName",String.class,"lastName");

List list = new ArrayList();
list.add(${username}); //Run time value
list.add(${emailId}); //Run time value
```

then **`EnitityManager.find(dynamicType.getJavaClass(),list)`** will take these arguments , am i right?
If i am assuming correct then how will `EnitityManager.find()` operation will know that List 1st argument is username or emailId pk value (means sequence of composite pk fields value) instead of Map `({username:${username},emailId:${emailId}})` or other DataStucture .

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should be able to use a List with the find() operation.

Comment: Updated my question in response to your. Please confirm my understanding on the solution proposed by you.

Comment: The order is the same as you defined the primary key fields in